# Windows 8.1 Admin account is logging in as a user account

Tags: windows-8.1, permissions, user-accounts, file-permissions, administrator

This one has me completely lost so I hope there's someone out there who can help.

I'm running Windows 8.1, I have the only account that has ever been on the computer and when I set it up I set it as the Admin account. I've never had a single problem with this until today.

I was trying to set up a virtual host which requires me to update the system hosts file. No problem, I went in and made the change only to be told that I don't have permission to save to that location. I checked the security tab of the properties and discovered that there were two entries for me under "Groups or user names;" one of them is called Administrators(Me\Administrators) the other Users(Me\Users). The administrator account has the correct permissions to update the file but the user account doesn't and as I can't update the file I can only assume that the computer has decided to log me in as a user instead of an administrator.

I've checked my account settings and they are telling me that I am an administrator and that my account is the only one on the computer, how can this be?

Is anyone able to suggest where I go from here as I've failed to find a solution by myself.

Comment: Use Far Manager http://www.farmanager.com/download.php?l=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to edit a read-only file. First remove the read-only flag in the file properties. Then try editing the file.

Start the editor with admin privileges:
Search in start menu > right click > run as administrator or Hold Control and Shift and start the editor then try again

Comment: I wish it were that easy. The read only box in the file attributes isn't ticked :-(

Comment: I've updated my answer

Comment: Okay, please don't forget to mark the problem as solved my accepting my answer :-)